# How can I manipulate an element coming from a PHP file by Ajax with jQuery 1.10?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an website ajax based that when the users make the login, another page is dinamically loaded. On this page, I have a div with an id called "portal-contacts", and I need to populate  this div with one more ajax call. Here is the code from the beginning:

1) When the users log in, I execute this $.ajax() (note: the 'complete' is from another Ajax call, that verify the users login and password, this is working fine):

---

```
    complete:function(jqXHR,textStatus){
        if(textStatus == "success"){
            $("#login-submit").removeAttr('disabled')
                .css('visibility','hidden');
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                dataType:"json",
                url:"functions/portal.php",
                async:true,
                data:null,
                success:function(response){
                    $("#login-window").fadeOut();
                    $("#container").hide().fadeIn().html(response.msg);
                },
                error:function(error,msg,errort){},
                complete:function(jqXHR,textStatus){}
            });
        }
    }
```

2) The "functions/portal.php" file:

---

```
            <div class='portal-content'>
                <div id='portal-contacts'></div>
            </div>
            <script type='text/javascript'>load_portal();</script>
```

3) The "load_portal()" function:

---

```
 function load_portal() {
      $("#portal-contacts).innerHTML = "Hi World";
 }
```

But it's not working. I already tried:

---

```
            $("#portal-contacts").click(function(){
                $(this).innerHTML = "Oi";
            });
            $("#portal-contacts").trigger("click");
```

---

```
            $("#portal-contacts").on("click",function(){
                $(this).innerHTML = "Hi World";
            });
            $("#portal-contacts").trigger("click");
```

---

```
            $("#portal-contacts").ready(function(){
                $(this).innerHTML = "Hi World";
            });
```

No one of this worked, can anyone helps me? Thank you.

Comment: Try `.html('Hi World')` instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: Ok, it worked. But why innerHTML didn't work? Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Because `.innerHTML` is a property of a dom element, but `$(this)` returns a jQuery object.

Comment: @Jason has it right. `innerHTML` is a standard JavaScript property, whereas `.html()` is a jQuery function that can be called on the selection returned by `$()`.